# Opencms: Copy and Paste Configuration file of modules to another node

Tags: configuration, opencms

I have OpenCms 10.5.4
I have three nodes with opencms.

I created some resources on the main node but they do not appear in the other nodes because in the other nodes the opencms configuration file "opencms-modules.xml" is not updated.

Is it enough to copy and paste this file into the other nodes to keep everything updated or is there something else to do?